# react-router-dom v6 error; "no exported member" when attempting to firebase deploy

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to deploy to firebase, but I keep getting the following error when I "firebase deploy":

```
=== Deploying to 'korchiedotcom'...

i  deploying functions, hosting
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run build

> build
> tsc

../node_modules/@types/react-router-dom/index.d.ts:13:10 - error TS2305: Module '"react-router"' has no exported member 'match'.

13 import { match } from 'react-router';
            ~~~~~

../node_modules/@types/react-router-dom/index.d.ts:19:5 - error TS2305: Module '"react-router"' has no exported member 'PromptProps'.

19     PromptProps,
       ~~~~~~~~~~~

../node_modules/@types/react-router-dom/index.d.ts:20:5 - error TS2305: Module '"react-router"' has no exported member 'Prompt'.

20     Prompt,
       ~~~~~~

../node_modules/@types/react-router-dom/index.d.ts:23:5 - error TS2305: Module '"react-router"' has no exported member 'RedirectProps'.

23     RedirectProps,
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../node_modules/@types/react-router-dom/index.d.ts:24:5 - error TS2724: '"react-router"' has no exported member named 'Redirect'. Did you mean 'redirect'?

24     Redirect,
       ~~~~~~~~

../node_modules/@types/react-router-dom/index.d.ts:25:5 - error TS2305: Module '"react-router"' has no exported member 'RouteChildrenProps'.

25     RouteChildrenProps,
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../node_modules/@types/react-router-dom/index.d.ts:26:5 - error TS2305: Module '"react-router"' has no exported member 'RouteComponentProps'.

26     RouteComponentProps,
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../node_modules/@types/react-router-dom/index.d.ts:31:5 - error TS2305: Module '"react-router"' has no exported member 'StaticRouterProps'.

31     StaticRouterProps,
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../node_modules/@types/react-router-dom/index.d.ts:32:5 - error TS2305: Module '"react-router"' has no exported member 'StaticRouter'.

32     StaticRouter,
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~

../node_modules/@types/react-router-dom/index.d.ts:33:5 - error TS2305: Module '"react-router"' has no exported member 'SwitchProps'.

33     SwitchProps,
       ~~~~~~~~~~~

../node_modules/@types/react-router-dom/index.d.ts:34:5 - error TS2305: Module '"react-router"' has no exported member 'Switch'.

34     Switch,
       ~~~~~~

../node_modules/@types/react-router-dom/index.d.ts:35:5 - error TS2305: Module '"react-router"' has no exported member 'match'.

35     match,
       ~~~~~

../node_modules/@types/react-router-dom/index.d.ts:37:5 - error TS2305: Module '"react-router"' has no exported member 'withRouter'.

37     withRouter,
       ~~~~~~~~~~

../node_modules/@types/react-router-dom/index.d.ts:38:5 - error TS2305: Module '"react-router"' has no exported member 'RouterChildContext'.

38     RouterChildContext,
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../node_modules/@types/react-router-dom/index.d.ts:39:5 - error TS2305: Module '"react-router"' has no exported member 'useHistory'.

39     useHistory,
       ~~~~~~~~~~

../node_modules/@types/react-router-dom/index.d.ts:42:5 - error TS2724: '"react-router"' has no exported member named 'useRouteMatch'. Did you mean 'RouteMatch'?

42     useRouteMatch,
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Found 16 errors in the same file, starting at: ../node_modules/@types/react-router-dom/index.d.ts:13


Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code 2
```

I am running the latest versions of typescript and react-router-dom. I've tried re-installing react-router-dom and updating it. I've even tried messing around a little bit with the node_modules/@types/react-router-dom/index.ts file-- and then changing it back to its default.

Any suggestions? I've hit a brick wall here!

Thank you!

Comment: When does `npm install` run?

Comment: I installed it initially when I first created the app, but I have since uninstalled it, reinstalled it, tried to fun the repair thing as well.

Comment: `npm install` have to run before each `build` on the server

Comment: is this something I can fix after i've already ran build and deploy?

Comment: No, you have to change your deploy script

Answer (score 0):

You could try removing the `@types/react-router-dom` dependency, in v6 types were shipped in `react-router-dom`.